# Redirect WordPress page to the latest created post by the logged in author/user

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a basic WordPress code that redirects someone to the last post type created on the site, in this case, is the "case" post type:

```
    <?php 
/*
Template Name: Redirect
*/

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post_type' => 'case'
);
$post = get_posts($args);
if($post){
    $url = get_permalink($post[0]->ID);
    wp_redirect( $url, 301 ); 
    exit;
}
```

I'm trying to expand on this code so I redirect people to their own created posts only, so they will be redirected to the last post they created with an added parameter like ?mode=edit to the end of the URL and if they're not logged in, they are going to be sent to a pre-defined error page, like domain.com/error.

I'm a bit new to PHP and for the life of me, I can't figure it out. Any input or hints are appreciated.

My plan is to insert this code into the page or pages that we're going to use as redirect points so the code will be embedded into the WordPress page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your code only slightly to add into your `get_posts()` call, the 'author' argument, set to current user's ID, if there is a current user having an ID.

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Redirect
*/

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post_type' => 'case'
);

global $current_user;
if( $current_user && isset( $current_user->ID ) ) $args[ 'author' ] = $current_user->ID;
$post = get_posts($args);
if($post){
    $url = get_permalink($post[0]->ID);
    wp_redirect( $url, 301 ); 
    exit;
}
```

This gets them to their most recent post. To Edit you can add into your single post template a hyperlink where user can Edit the post.

Comment: I added an else condition for the error page but the biggest issue is that it still redirects even when they're not logged in. Any thoughts on this?